# Authenticate OpenVPN users via Radius (Freeradius)

Tags: authentication, openvpn, freeradius, pam, radius

I have set up OpenVPN server (not the access server, the open source community version) and Freeradius 3 on my ubuntu machine. OpenVPN client authentication has been tested for both username/password and certificate/key mechanisms for users generated using Easy-RSA. Freeradius user creation and testing have been done by daloradius and ntradping respectively.

What I want, is to use RADIUS authentication for my VPN clients. Basically when the client prompts for username password, I want to login via the credentials I have created in freeradius.

There is very little info about it on the official documentation page of OpenVPN [in this page](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/using-alternative-authentication-methods/)

While following the guide, I have found that the openvpn-auth-pam plugin has been renamed, relocated and now comes prebuilt (if it's not feel free to correct me, I assumed that because the openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so file was already there) [into a different directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEPKp.png)

According to the guide I have to add the following line to my server configuration file.

```
plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so [name of the module to be used for authentication]
```

So here I need to call for a module that calls freeradius to perform the authentication. The guide uses the "login" PAM module which is located at
**/etc/pam.d** directory, unless I found the wrong thing. In the same directory there is also a file named radiusd and the contents of the file are

> /* /etc/pam.d/radiusd - PAM configuration for FreeRADIUS */
>
> /* We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-* */
>
> @include common-auth
>
> @include common-account
>
> @include common-password
>
> @include common-session

I am not sure what to do next. Is freeradius's own PAM module even relevant to the operation that I am trying to perform? Or do I need to use some external tools and libraries to integrate freeradius with OpenVPN? Or I need to create the module file by myself? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Debian. Centos 7 is getting EOL soon. Centos 8+ does not have this plugin in repos, but you can compile it (see end of answer).

Install RADIUS authentication module and edit openvpn server configuration

```
apt update
# apt-cache search ".*openvpn.*radius.*"
apt install openvpn-auth-radius
# find / -name "radiusplugin*"
cp /usr/share/doc/openvpn-auth-radius/examples/radiusplugin.cnf /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
nano /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
```

Edit next sections in /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf. Rest - leave as is.

```
name=ip-of-your-radius
retry=10 # change if needed
wait=600 # change if needed
sharedsecret=paste-here-radius-secret
```

Server config

```
nano /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

Add lines:

```
# For auth plugins. Uncomment if needed
# username-as-common-name
 
# RADIUS Auth
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/radiusplugin.cnf
```

If you want to compile it (I didn't tested):

```
apt-get install libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev gcc make build-essential
wget http://www.nongnu.org/radiusplugin/radiusplugin_v2.1a_beta1.tar.gz
tar xvfz radiusplugin_v2.1a_beta1.tar.gz
cd radiusplugin_v2.1a_beta1/
make
cp radiusplugin.so /etc/openvpn/
cp radiusplugin.cnf /etc/openvpn/
```

List of OpenVPN plugins: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/PluginOverview

PS: similar algorithm for LDAP integration (find plugin in repo, use example config, add it in main config).

Answer (score 0):

plugin "**openvpn-auth-radius**" doesn't work with OpenVPN over 2.4.x so if you have OpenVPN version 2.5.x this plugin won't work.

the alternative solution is using custom authentication with radius client tool combined, this is how to do it.

you need to install package "**freeradius-utils**" this package available with all Linux repo.

```
apt install freeradius-utils
```

**server configuration file (server.conf)**

**add these lines to server config**

```
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/auth.sh via-env
username-as-common-name
verify-client-cert none
script-security 3
```

make sure to give it execute permission

```
chmod +x /etc/openvpn/auth.sh
```

create file auth.sh in /etc/openvpn/auth.sh

```
x="radtest $username $password radius_server_ip 1812 radius_sever_secret"
y=$(eval "$x")
 
if [[ $y == *"Access-Accept"* ]]; then
  exit 0
        else
  exit 1
fi
```

that's it